# three.js OrbitControls are not working, controls undefined

Tags: html, three.js

[I followed this quick tutorial from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rR88qSgmPOw)

When I comment this line out I have the working example without the controls.

```
//controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

But when I try to use the OrbitControls the log tells me the following:

```
(index):21 Uncaught ReferenceError: controls is not defined
    at (index):21
```

The content of my `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script type="module">

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 64, 64 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( sphere );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your controls like so:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

The mising `var` leads to the mentioned runtime error.

Comment: I removed the module type from the script tag and than it was working.
Thx a lot for the input anyway